# Change Sidebar for rewritten page

Tags: sidebar, rewrite-rules

I have a number of rewrite rules set which output content correctly however I want to extend this so that the sidebars that appear on that rewritten page can also be amended so that a sidebar is called depending on the `query_vars` used. Is there anyway to manipulate what is rendered with `dynamic_sidebar` so we can query the `query_vars` and choose an appropriate sidebar to display? Or is it a case of wrapping `dynamic_sidebar` with tests to call the correct sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell your exact requirements, but testing to see which handle to pass to `dynamic_sidebar` is probably your best bet, since it'll allow you to administer each version from the WordPress back-end. Don't forget to register each version with [`register_sidebar`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/)

The other thing that might be what you're after is the [`sidebars_widgets`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/sidebars_widgets/) filter, which lets you edit the global widgets array when it's accessed within `dynamic_sidebar`.

A sidebar is part of the template applied to the post/page, I can't see any way that changing it directly via a rewrite rule would make sense from a functional perspective.

Comment: I was overthinking this I think. What I wanted to achieve is to change the value used by `dynamic_sidebar` by accessing a filter when this function is called. (Now wondering whether it is worth possibly suggesting a filter to WP Core to amend this value at the beginning of that function) The simplest solution was to just use `get_query_var` and then call the relevant sidebar. I was trying to avoid overriding the template on which this appears by using a filter.

Comment: What you're describing would normally be done by editing the template. I recently had to dynamically switch sidebars, based on taxonomy, on a theme myself and that was by far the simplest method. From what you're saying, it sounds like you might be taking a very convoluted approach to what you're attempting to do. Perhaps if you amend your question to describe _exactly_ what you want to achieve from end to end?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I've accepted your answer as I did just end up performing tests before passing an appropriate handle to `dynamic_sidebar`